# How to call a polymorphic function with a val

Tags: scala

Given the following polymorphic method

```
def get[T](implicit m: ClassTag[T]) : Seq[T]
```

How can I call with the parameter from a val. Unfortunately the following doesn't compile :

```
val clazz = Class[Int]
get[clazz]
```

[update] I was trying to do :

```
val classes = List(String.getClass, Int.getClass)
classes.map { c => get(ClassTag(c)) }
```

Comment: For polymorphic functions, take a look at https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#polymorphic-function-values

Answer (score 1):

You can't supply a type parameter with a val like that, nor is `Class[Int]` a value. It's unclear what you really want to do.

You could use a type alias:

```
type C = Int
get[C]
```

You could explicitly look for a `ClassTag` using `classTag[A]`, which is essentially the same as providing a type hint to `get[A]`:

```
get(classTag[Int])
```

You could also get the `ClassTag` from a class instance, and explicitly pass it:

```
val ct: ClassTag[Int] = ClassTag(1.getClass)
get(ct)
```

None of these seem particularly useful.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve, but you can use a type alias:

```
type clazz = Class[Int]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly call it as :

```
 val result = get[Int](ClassTag[1]);
```